# TCP receive buffer

Tags: c, networking, tcp

What is the difference between the buffer referred to in C code like

```
recvfrom(sock, buffer, 20, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&c_addr, &addr_size);
```

and the buffer that can have its size adjusted by setting socket options (in C, but I think other programming languages have the same socket option)?

My confusion comes from the buffer referred to as "buffer" in the recvfrom code could be reasonably called a receive buffer, which is also the name of a buffer used in TCP. I want to clarify that the buffer mentioned in the recvfrom code is a different kind of buffer and perhaps what the difference is.

Assuming they are different, in terms of the 5-layer networking model, is the 2nd type of buffer basically just for the transport layer and not typically modifiable (apart from being able to change its general properties like size) at the application layer? In other words, is data in the TCP receive buffer passed up to the buffer called "buffer" in the recvfrom code?

Comment: [tag:osi] has nothing do with it, or with anything else for 20 years. Let it rest in peace.

Answer (score 0):

The receive buffer you're referring to is an internal buffer in the OS where incoming data is stored before the userspace program accesses it via a `recv` or `recvfrom` function call.

This differs from `buffer` in your code above as that is an application buffer.

If an application doesn't read packets faster than the OS is receiving them, the receive buffer in the OS will full up and packets will be dropped.

Comment: Packets won't be dropped because they won't be sent. TCP will close he receive window and the sender will stop sending.